# Is a Masters thesis in the public domain?

Tags: copyright, internet, academia

Is a Master's thesis submitted to the University of California Berkeley in the public domain (i.e., can be shared publicly by a person in USA on the internet without asking anybody's permission)?

Comment: Why would you think that it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The [general policy of the University of California](http://copyright.universityofcalifornia.edu/ownership/student-works.html) is that students and faculty retain the copyright of scholarly works they create.  So the thesis is copyrighted by its author (unless the author has since transferred copyright for some reason).

However, if you contact the author and ask politely, there is a good chance that they will give you permission to share it.

Comment: Indeed, our litigious American society tends to lose sight far too easily of the power of the polite request.

Comment: @phoog: Well, especially for an academic thesis, for which the author is usually interested in having it widely read, and for which the commercial value is usually nil.  You might also find that the author has posted the thesis on a personal website or open-access repository, which would even save you the trouble of circulating the document; just share a link.